# How to draw a 90 degree arc in using SVG element?

Tags: svg

How can I draw an arc of 90 degrees using only the SVG element?

E.g. I want the svg element to be 100 x 100px and the arc will be 90 degrees starting from the top point (50, 0), arcing to the right point (100, 50).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <path d="M 50,0 A 50,50 0 0 1 100,50" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```